# Jquery Datatable: here we go again with horizontal scroll like Excell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

**The goal**

Create an easier way to scroll Jquery Datatable (horizontally)

**The problem:**

Double scroll sucks, because it doesn't work properly, sometimes top scroll doesn't scroll datatable until the end, but bottom scroll works fine.

Another think that I tried without success: on mobile, you can scroll with swipe. Would be awesome do that on desktop by holding click.

**How can we achieve this:**

1- Scroll horizontally by holding left click and moving right/left;

2- Remove Datatable scrolls and have only one fixed "scroll" that whould command jquery datatable horizontal scroll;

3- Or maybe the datatable bottom scroll be fixed at page bottom?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

First, let's add this options on datatable:

```
"scrollY":        screen.height / 2,
"scrollCollapse": true,
```

This will make sure datatable dont strech vertically when there's too many rows and will show scroll.

Now I just have to make sure this height let the horizontal bar always showing, now that contents get scrolled inside datatable.